# Read the messages of the public channels from Telegram

Tags: telegram, python-telegram-bot

I need to read the messages of some public channels in the application, as, for example, happens https://tlgrm.ru/channels/tech. As I understood, the bot for this business will not work. You need to use client api, but everywhere that with the channel methods are connected everywhere you need channel_id but where do I get it I do not know, I only have channel names, and how do I get it from it id I did not find such a method.

How can I get the channel's id by its name?

Comment: The current answers here are out of date, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58665178/4759433 is a duplicated with newer answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're using python, I suggest [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) library. You can use this piece of code to get `channel_id` and `access_hash` from `@username`:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest

client = TelegramClient(session_file, api_id=X, api_hash='X')
client.connect()
response = client.invoke(ResolveUsernameRequest("username"))
print(response.channel_id)
print(response.access_hash)
```

Make sure you have already got your `api_id` and `api_hash`. And also make sure you have authenticated your app i.e. you have a working `session_file`. Just read Telethon's README in the Github page if you're not sure how to perform above steps.

Comment: AttributeError: 'TelegramClient' object has no attribute 'invoke'

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version, you would do like this using the username of the channel

```
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
response = client.invoke(ResolveUsernameRequest(<username>))
messages = client.get_message_history(response.peer,limit=1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the other type of Telegram API: [Telegram [client] API and TDLib](https://core.telegram.org/#tdlib-build-your-own-telegram)

Using [telethon library](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) makes it easy to read channels history (see [telethon docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/installation.html)).

For this, we need an `api_id` and an `api_hash`.  So, do the following:

1. Log in to [Telegram core](https://my.telegram.org/)
2. Open the [API development tools area](https://my.telegram.org/apps)
3. Fill out the simple form there
4. Now you can receive your `api_id` and `api_hash`
   <sub>For more information, see Telegram's help documentation about [how to get your API credentials](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id).</sub>

Here is an example code that gets the last *5* messages of *targetChannelId*:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient


API_ID = 123456     # See above for how to get it
API_HASH = '123abc' # See above for how to get it
client = TelegramClient('my-client', API_ID, API_HASH)


async def main():
    async for message in client.iter_messages('targetChannelId', limit=5):
        print(message.id, message.text)


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The first time you run this code it asks your phone number or bot token. Enter your **phone number** in the format `+9912345...` where `99` is your country code and the rest is your phone number.
It then may send a login code to your Telegram app; enter it in the console.

**Note**: Only users (phone numbers) can see channel history messages; bots cannot (at least in telethon). Bots can only listen for channel **updates** only if they are one of its **administrators**.

The `client.iter_messages()` accepts other parameters like `min_id` which can be used to get messages only after a specific message (for example, we can save the last message id that we have processed and next time pass that id as `min_id` so only messages after that message are returned).