# Read public channel texts using Telegram API

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, channel, telethon

I would like to create a small script that will fetch Telegram texts from a public channel (I am not the channel's admin).

I've found another question asked here:
[Read the messages of the public channels from Telegram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525921/read-the-messages-of-the-public-channels-from-telegram)

I've tried using Telethon as said in the answer, but it didn't work:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
import telethon

client = telethon.TelegramClient("session.txt", api_id=XYZ, api_hash='XYZ')
client.connect()
response = client.invoke(ResolveUsernameRequest("test"))
print(response.channel_id)
print(response.access_hash)
```

Throwing this error:

```
C:/Users/mypc/PycharmProjects/untitled/aa.py:5: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'TelegramBaseClient.connect' was never awaited
  client.connect()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mypc/PycharmProjects/untitled/aa.py", line 6, in <module>
    response = client.invoke(ResolveUsernameRequest("test"))
AttributeError: 'TelegramClient' object has no attribute 'invoke'
```

I've tried reading the API documentation, but I didn't fully understand how those calls work:

> https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.exportMessageLink
>
> https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.joinChannel
>
> https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.getMessages

I'd be grateful if someone could explain to me how those work.

Comment: `client.invoke(request)` is the old way to do it. You need to use `client(request)`.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73270188/8583692) for how to read channel past messages using a user account.

Answer (score 3):

That answer is very old. If we check [Telethon's Quick-Start](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/quick-start.html) we have enough code to do what you need:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient

# Remember to use your own values from my.telegram.org!
api_id = 12345
api_hash = '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    # You can print the message history of any chat:
    async for message in client.iter_messages('USERNAME OF THE CHANNEL'):
        print(message.sender.username, message.text)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: But, how do you connect your bot to listen public channel messages? Your code does not answer the question.

Comment: The code answers the question fine ("fetch text from a public channel"). Actively listen for incoming messages is a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Well like it says, `TelegramClient` has no `invoke` method. Have you tried `client(ResolveUsernameRequest("test"))`?

Comment: It would be more helpful to note that `invoke` was the old way of doing it, and refer to the page that explains how full API is done. In addition, there's a friendly method which is a far better alternative.

Comment: Fair. I didn't know it was the old way of doing it, seeing as I'm still fairly new to Telethon